# Discord Bot Reaction Collector with Javascript

Tags: node.js, bots, discord

I'm currently working on a discord bot poll command, and the poll itself works fine, however I'm having some trouble with displaying the results of the poll.

```
async function votingResults(awaitTime) {

const reactions = await msg.awaitReactions(reaction => reaction => reaction.emoji.name === "" || 

reaction.emoji.name === "", {time: awaitTime}).catch((err) => { 
        console.error('Error ' + err);
    });

    console.log("Ended");

    var pollResults = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(pink)
        .setTitle('POLL ENDED')
        .setAuthor('IdealBot', 'https://hypixel.net/attachments/ideal-png.1417277/', 'https://hypixel.net/threads/ideal-ideal-%E2%9D%96-level-52-%E2%9D%96-sweaty-skyblock-guild-%E2%9D%96-top-10-sb-guild-%E2%9D%96-splashes-%E2%9D%96-events-%E2%9D%96-recruiting.2500755/')
        .addFields(
            { name: 'Question', value: pollArgs[0] },
            { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' }
        )
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter('Ideal bot v 1.2 [BETA]');
    for (i = 2; i < pollArgs.length; i++) {
        console.log(reactions);
        pollResults.addFields({ name: 'Option ' + pollReact[i - 2], value: pollArgs[i] + `\nVotes: **${reactions.get(pollReact[i-2])-1}**`, inline: true });
    }
    pollResults.addFields({ name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' });

    msg.channel.send(pollResults).catch((err) => {
        console.error('Error!' + err);
    })
}

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {

    msg = message;

    if (message.channel.id == '689423653389336636' || message.channel.id == '691039595348885564' || message.channel.id == '693094055533346826') {
        if (args.length < 8) {
            message.channel.send(pollUsage);
            message.delete();
        }
        else {
            pollMsg = message.content.slice(6, message.length);
            pollArgs = pollMsg.split("/"); // Splits arguments by "/"

            if (pollArgs.length > 11) {
                message.channel.send(pollUsage);
                message.delete();
            }
            else {

                var timeArgs = pollArgs[1].split(":");

                var days = parseInt(timeArgs[0]);
                var hours = parseInt(timeArgs[1]);
                var minutes = parseInt(timeArgs[2]);
                var seconds = parseInt(timeArgs[3]);

                if (timeArgs.length < 5) {
                    var pollEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor(pink)
                        .setTitle('POLL')
                        .setAuthor('IdealBot', 'https://hypixel.net/attachments/ideal-png.1417277/', 'https://hypixel.net/threads/ideal-ideal-%E2%9D%96-level-52-%E2%9D%96-sweaty-skyblock-guild-%E2%9D%96-top-10-sb-guild-%E2%9D%96-splashes-%E2%9D%96-events-%E2%9D%96-recruiting.2500755/')
                        .addFields(
                            { name: 'Question', value: pollArgs[0] },
                            { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' }
                        )
                        .setTimestamp()
                        .setFooter('Time left: ' + pollArgs[1]);
                    for (i = 2; i < pollArgs.length; i++) {
                        pollEmbed.addFields({ name: 'Option ' + pollReact[i - 2], value: pollArgs[i], inline: true });
                    }
                    pollEmbed.addFields({ name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' });

                    var secDays = days * 24 * 60 * 60;
                    var secHours = hours * 60 * 60;
                    var secMinutes = minutes * 60;

                    console.log("New poll successfully created! Ending in " + pollArgs[1] + "!");

                    var totalTime = secDays + secHours + secMinutes + seconds;
                    var totalTimeMilliseconds = totalTime * 1000;

                    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
                    var endDate = currentTime + totalTimeMilliseconds;

                    msg = message.channel.send(pollEmbed).then(sentEmbed => {
                        for (i = 2; i < pollArgs.length; i++) {
                            sentEmbed.react(pollReactEmoji[i - 2])
                        }

                        votingResults(totalTimeMilliseconds);

                        var timer = setInterval(function () {
                            var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
                            var remainingTime = endDate - currentTime;

                            if (remainingTime >= 0) {

                                let daysCalc = Math.floor(remainingTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                                let hoursCalc = Math.floor((remainingTime % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                                let minutesCalc = Math.floor((remainingTime % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                                let secondsCalc = Math.floor((remainingTime % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

                                if (daysCalc < 10) { daysCalc = "0" + daysCalc };
                                if (hoursCalc < 10) { hoursCalc = "0" + hoursCalc };
                                if (minutesCalc < 10) { minutesCalc = "0" + minutesCalc };
                                if (secondsCalc < 10) { secondsCalc = "0" + secondsCalc };

                                var remainingTimeText = daysCalc + ":" + hoursCalc + ":" + minutesCalc + ":" + secondsCalc;

                                pollEmbed.setFooter('Time left: ' + remainingTimeText);

                                sentEmbed.edit(pollEmbed).catch((err) => {
                                    console.error('Error! ' + err);
                                })

                            }
                            else {
                                pollEmbed.setFooter('Poll expired!');

                                sentEmbed.edit(pollEmbed).catch((err) => {
                                    console.error('Error!' + err);
                                })
                            }
                        }, 1000);
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        console.error('Error! ' + err)
                    })
                    message.delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to run the code, I get an error:

> TypeError: msg.awaitReactions is not a function

I don't understand this, as I defined `msg` as the message.

Comment: you didn't define `msg` as the message, it's a global variable you're reusing several times, and sometimes you have `msg = message.channel.send().then(...);` which is a *promise* and not a message. why use this convoluted global variable when you can just... pass the message as an argument to `votingResults`? like this: `votingResults(totalTimeMilliseconds, sentEmbed)`?

Comment: Ohh, thank you, didnt think of that!